# What is the Alternate for getDefaultDisplay()

Tags: java, android

I am getting waring `getDefaultDisplay()` is deprecated. Need to use `Context.getDisplay()`. But below **R** version what we need to use? Please help me on this.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    display = mContext.getDisplay();
} else {
    ((Activity) mContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); //Deprecated
}
```